# Is this patent expired? And if not, does it have a worldwide patent?

Tags: patent-lifetime

I don't understand how to read the patent page. From the snapshot, is this patent granted and still effect? If so, does it only apply to USA or Worldwide? Thanks.[image]

Comment: As pointed out in answers there is no such thing as a world-wide patent although there is an *almost* world-wide way of applying for a patent. There are, as of January 2024, 157 countries that can be reached by the PCT process. A few are missing, prominently including  Argentina and Taiwan. After filing each place you actually want protection in needs to be addressed with further process and payments. https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/pct_contracting_states.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application cited was granted as [US9016652B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9016652B2/en?oq=us20120235004). Normally one would expect that patent to expire 08-20-2029. However it costs money to maintain a patent and it looks like the patent  has expired due to non payment of required fees. Similarly for [US8201796B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8201796B2/en?oq=US8201796B2) by the same inventor. These are US patents. There are no worldwide patents. Patents are specific to countries. I found a [world patent application](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2011022587A2/en?oq=us20120235004). But it doesn't look like it has issued anywhere. I'm not sure whether or not the fee related expiration can be overcome, but for now the US patents shouldn't be enforceable.

Just to note, I am not a lawyer so this isn't legal advice. Avoiding infringement on one patent doesn't guarantee freedom to operate over all patents. If you want to be safe, you should absolutely engage an attorney to determine if you have freedom to operate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the publication of an US patent application *not* a granted patent.

There are no worldwide patents. However, there is such a thing as sn (almost) worldwide patent *application* via the PCT process of WIPO.